# How to check the verbose status of a thread's "shared state" or "memory state"? How to not make calls to std::async( ) block?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

My method that uses multithreading is:

```
typedef std::pair<std::vector<char>, int> PATH_PAIR;

std::list<PATH_PAIR>
TSP::return_all_paths_list(
    PATH_PAIR                                       parent_path_pair,
    std::list<char>                                 unvisited_cities
) {
    std::list<PATH_PAIR>                            subseq_paths_list;
    std::vector<std::future<std::list<PATH_PAIR>>>  future_vec;
   
    if (unvisited_cities.empty()) { // END RECURSION
        // NON-REALTED CODE
        return subseq_paths_list;
    }

    for (const char curr_city: unvisited_cities) {   // DO RECURSION
        PATH_PAIR                           new_path_pair_addr = parent_path_pair;
        std::list<char>                     subseq_unvisited_cities = unvisited_cities;
        std::future<std::list<PATH_PAIR>>   returned_path_list_future;
        // NON-RELATED CODE
        returned_path_list_future = std::move(std::async(std::launch::async, return_all_paths_list, this, new_path_pair_addr, subseq_unvisited_cities));

        future_vec.push_back(returned_path_list_future);
    }

    while (!future_vec.empty()) {   // GET-VALUES-WHILE
        for (std::future<std::list<PATH_PAIR>>& curr_future : future_vec)  // GET-VALUES-FOR
            if (curr_future.valid()) {
                subseq_paths_list.merge(curr_future.get());
            }
        // future_list.remove_if(
        //     [] (std::future<std::list<PATH_PAIR>> input_future) -> bool {
        //         return !input_future.valid();
        //     }
        // );
    }

    return subseq_paths_list;
}
```

I have a few questions:

1. As per [cppreference std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async):

   > If the std::future obtained from std::async is not moved from or bound to a reference, the destructor of the std::future will block at the end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes, essentially making code such as the following synchronous:
   >
   > ```
   > std::async(std::launch::async, []{ f(); }); // temporary's dtor waits for f()
   > std::async(std::launch::async, []{ g(); }); // does not start until f() completes
   > ```

   **a**. What do the words "move from" and "bound to a reference" mean?
   **b**. Will wrapping the call to `std::async` inside an `std::move` make the calls to `std::async` not block in the suceeding iterations of `// DO RECURSION` loop?
   **c**. Or are the calls in the above two lines blocking just because lambdas are used?
2. How do I check if a shared state is *ready*?
   **a**. A call to `std::future::wait` (and `std::future::get`) blocks until the shared state is *ready*. The thing is, I don't want to wait. I want to check if a shared state is *ready*, if it's not, I want to move on to the next `std::future` object. How do I do that? `std::future::valid` only checks if a shared state is *associated* with an object.
   **b**. Also, again as per [cppreference std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), the return value of a call to `std::async` is:

   > [std::future](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) referring to the shared state created by this call to `std::async`

   So, in the `//GET VALUES` loops, the `std::future` obtained will always return `true` if `std::future::valid` is called on it (provided `std::future::get` isn't called on it yet). If I remove an `std::future` after an `std::future::get` is called, I don't **have** to check the validity of the `std::future` objects. But, none of the *remove element* STL methods I've tried don't work, there's compile time errors spanning to about twice the height of my display.

   I thought, maybe calling `std::future::get` also destroys the object in addition to *releasing* the shared state, but a small test piece of code I wrote:

   ```
   int mul2(int x) {return x << 1; }
   int main() {
       std::vector<std::future<int>> fut_vec;
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           fut_vec.push_back(std::move(std::async(std::launch::async, mul2, i)));
       }
       for (std::vector<std::future<int>>::iterator itr = fut_vec.begin(); itr != fut_vec.end(); itr++) {
           if (itr->valid()) {
               std::cout << "Value: " << itr->get() << " | No. of vec elements(futures): " << fut_vec.size() << std::endl;
           }
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   reveals the `fut_vec.size()` always returns the same integer.

   How do I destroy an `std::future` object?

I recently got into multithreading, so now I'm trying to implement the travelling salesman problem using multithreading.

Comment: `std::future<T>::wait_for` and `std::future<T>::wait_until`

Comment: Questions on stack overflow should only contain one question. Why would `fut_vec` decrease in size? There's nothing in your code to remove elements from it?

Comment: @273K those are time bound. Besides, I DON'T want to wait.

Comment: @AlanBirtles There's nothing in my code that removes elements from `fut_vec` because methods to remove an element (which is `std::future` in this case) give compile-time errors

Comment: You can `wait_for(0s)` then. If you get an error, post the complete error message (in the question, not in the comment). Usually, the first error is the most relevant one.

Comment: In C++, objects are destroyed by a destructor. For objects of an automatic storage duration, this happens when the program execution reaches the point that is out of the scope the object was created in. For dynamic storage duration,  this happens when `delete` is called on the pointer.

Comment: @heapunderrun  what part of my code would possibly return an error if I `wait_for(0s)`? Won't using `get` just make me again wait until the shared state is ready?

Comment: Regarding question 1a, this is just a reminder that you have to store the returned `std::future` somewhere. For "usual" types, this is done by assinging or copy-constructing from them. But `std::future` is a move-only type. Thus, you have to instead either move-assign or move-construct to the other object. (Not storing the returned future is also "OK", but then the temporary will be waiting for destruction right away, causing it to turn into a blocking call, so what's the point?)

Comment: @heapunderrun Totally forgot about `delete`. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to `delete` if you never call `new`. For example, `std::vector` manages its own memory by itself (invoking `new` in `push_back` or `emplace_back`, and `delete` on `pop_back`, `resize` etc.).

Comment: My comment regarding error messages was a general one, not about `wait_for`. But anyway, you have to split this long question in five or six. "One question per question", those are StackOverflow rules.

Comment: @heapunderrun Does me using `std::async` inside `std::move` block?

Comment: "Moved from" means "appears on the right-hand side of a move constructor or a move assignment operator". Practically speaking, the shared state is transferred from this future to another; this future becomes empty and so there's nothing to block on in its destructor.

Comment: "Bound to a reference" means "used to initialized a variable of reference type". This is significant because it extends the lifetime of the temporary to that of the reference. As in `const std::future<Something>& f = std::async(...);` (the future returned by `async` is destroyed when `f` goes out of scope, not at the semicolon).

Comment: It's not the call to `std::async` that blocks - it's the destructor of the `future` returned by it that may block under some circumstances. A more precise wording is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future):  "[future destructor] may block if all of the following are true: (1) the shared state was created by a call to `std::async,` (2) the shared state is not yet ready, and (3) the current object was the last reference to the shared state." This formulation doesn't depend on whether an object has been moved from.

Comment: `future_vec.push_back(returned_path_list_future);` won't compile - it attempts to make a copy of `returned_path_list_future` but `std::future` is not copyable. Can you show an example that actually compiles? It would be best to prepare a [mcve]

Comment: The call `std::async(std::launch::async, []{ f(); });` may block because it returns a temporary `std::future` which is not saved anywhere but is immediately destroyed. It is this destructor that may block, because it satisfies the three conditions listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future)

Answer (score 0):

To check if a shared state of a future is ready, wait for 0 seconds on it.  If it is ready, it will say so; if not, it will time out.

The blocking behavior of the std async return future is passed on to whatever you move it to.  The blocking behavior is in the *shared state*, not in the specific future returned.

Destroying an object has nothing to do with your multithreading problem.

You have to keep around the futures returned from std async until you know the task is finished, then you can destroy them.  If you destroy them earlier, you will block on the task finishing.

Typically creating an unbounded number of parallel threads is a bad plan for any program.  Typical parallel code creates a pool of *tasks* to work on, and then uses a pool of threads to work on those tasks.

Directly creating threads (or be it via std::thread or std::async) and giving it a single task to work on is a bit like manually managing memory.  Sure, it can solve problems, but it isn't best practices.

...

What I'd do is make a threadsafe queue of `T` using `std::condition_variable`, `std::mutex` and `std::deque`.  Add methods `push`, `pop`.

Then I'd make a threadpool.  The threadpool owns a threadsafe queue of `std::packaged_task<void>`.  It has a `std::future<void> start_task( std::function<void()> )` method.  This future, unlike the `std::async` one, does not block on destruction.

The threadpool maintains (hardware_concurrency_count) threads, be the `std::thread` or `std::async` created, and each thread pops a task off of the threadsafe queue, does it, then repeats.

Maybe add a `wait_until_all_tasks_done` to your `threadpool`, as well as a `terminate_all_tasks`.

You can write unit tests for your threadsafe queue and your thread pool outside of your TSP problem, and then solve the TSP using these two primitives without having to mess with buggy threading code at the same time.